# How to add map to a iOS 14 widget?

Tags: swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

I add `Map` to iOS Widget but it doesn't work.

```
 VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: nil, content: {
  Text("Placeholder")
                    
  Map(coordinateRegion: $reg, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode:$trackmode)
  Spacer()
})
```

[image]

Comment: Widget is now limited to show static only content.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some views appear as a red no entry sign in widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63135404/why-do-some-views-appear-as-a-red-no-entry-sign-in-widgets)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could try to display image snapshot for required map's area