# Prevent default app opening on ios widget click

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I have a widget made using widgetkit extension which have four tappable icons which opens specific screen in the app using deeplinks.

```
 Link(destination: URL(string: deepLinkUrl)!) {
    ..... //tappable UI components
  }
```

However, on tapping the area outside the icons, i.e the widget itself(the blank area), it opens the app by default. Is there any way to stop this default behaviour. Similar to Today widgets like whatsapp,snapchat

Comment: The best way to avoid it is to avoid having "blank" areas on the widget. Also, remember that the `Link` doesn't work for the smallest size widget.

Comment: This is currently not possible. See [How to prevent iOS 14 Widget opening app and react to callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65115917/how-to-prevent-ios-14-widget-opening-app-and-react-to-callback)