# Widget without using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, storyboard

Is it possible to create a widget in iOS 14+ without using SwiftUI? When adding the target it doesn't give you the option between storyboard and SwiftUI like it does when creating a new project. Is it possible to build out a Widget using Storyboard or XIB?

Comment: You can only use SwiftUI for building widgets. This post lists the types of views that you can use when building a widget https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63135404/why-do-some-views-appear-as-a-red-no-entry-sign-in-widgets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible to create a widget without using SwiftUI. Here's what [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit#) says:

> To implement a widget, you add a widget extension to your app. You configure the widget with a timeline provider, and use SwiftUI views to display the widget’s content. The timeline provider tells WidgetKit when to update your widget’s content.

Comment: I hate my life.

Comment: Can we add widget using SwiftUI in Swift project ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create a widget without an app, you could use [Scriptable](https://scriptable.app), where you write your code in JavaScript and can use native components for your UI.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: Is this a valid technical solution, or a generic approach? WidgetKit has some specific requirements.