# SwiftUI cannot show SpriteView in live activities

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit, widgetkit, widgetliveactivity

I am trying to show a sprite view in an app. I already have it showing as a view on the main app and it works perfectly fine. The problem comes when I try and add it as a view using

```swift
var characterView: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: characterScene)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    }
```

and just showing that view.

Here is some minimal code:

```swift
// Character Animation
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class CharacterScene: SKScene {
    let characterName: String
    init(characterName: String) {
        self.characterName = characterName
        super.init(size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 400))
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    var textures: [SKTexture] = []
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: characterName)
        textures = atlas.textureNames.sorted().map { atlas.textureNamed($0) }
        
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: textures[0])
        let maxSize: CGFloat = 200
        let aspectRatio = sprite.size.height / sprite.size.width
        sprite.size = CGSize(width: min(sprite.size.width, maxSize), height: min(sprite.size.height, maxSize * aspectRatio))
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        addChild(sprite)
        
        let animation = SKAction.animate(with: textures, timePerFrame: 0.5)
        sprite.run(SKAction.repeatForever(animation))
    }
}

//Widget

import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import ActivityKit
import SpriteKit

struct CharacterIslandWidget: Widget {
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        ActivityConfiguration(
            for: CharacterIslandAttributes.self,
            content: { context in
                CharacterIslandWidgetView(context: context)
            },
            dynamicIsland: { context in
                DynamicIsland(
                    expanded: {
                        DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.center) {
                            Text(context.state.CharacterName)
                        }
                        DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.leading) {
                            SpriteView(scene: CharacterScene(characterName: context.state.CharacterImage))
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        }
                    },
                    compactLeading: {
                        SpriteView(scene: CharacterScene(characterName: context.state.CharacterImage))
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    },
                    compactTrailing: {
                    },
                    minimal: {
                        SpriteView(scene: CharacterScene(characterName: context.state.CharacterImage))
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    })
            }
    )}
}
struct CharacterIslandWidgetView: View {
    let context: ActivityViewContext<CharacterIslandAttributes>
    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: CharacterScene(characterName: context.state.CharacterImage))
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        Text(context.state.CharacterImage)
    }
}
```

I don't get any executable errors in the logs, so I don't exactly know the problem, but the image looks like this (I don't have previews set up for the widgets yet).

[image: image error]

The atlas name is given below the image and is correct as it is running perfectly fine in the app.

A few extra things:

- The asset folder is shared between the widget and app, and it works because it shows up on the app.
- context.state.CharacterImage is the atlas "folder" name which has all the sprites.

How do I go about this from here? Are sprite views not allowed in Live Activities (Dynamic Island)?

I tried hardcoding names, and reading error logs, but nothing showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgets only support a subset of SwiftUI views and live activities are a special kind of widget. Apple documents the [SwiftUI views that can be used in widgets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/swiftui-views).

The red no entry symbol seems to be displayed when trying to use an unsupported SwiftUI view ([Why do some views appear as a red no entry sign in widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63135404/why-do-some-views-appear-as-a-red-no-entry-sign-in-widgets))

Comment: Thats what I initially thought. Thank you! Ill find a new way of going about this problem then!